# How to move inner class to outer

Tags: intellij-idea

There is an inner class , e.g.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    @Data
    public static class Award {
        private final int id;
        private final String name;
    }
}
```

I want to move `Award` out of `Foo`, can `Intellij IDEA` support it? I tried selecting the code then choose `Move` menu of `Refactor` menu. But it hints
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no need in selecting entire class, just click on class name and call `Refactor - Move` (<kbd>F6</kbd> hotkey). Something like this will happen:

[image]

Comment: it's always trying to move Foo this way, how can I tell him to move Award, it's highlighted just like in your screenshot and still it's moving Foo

Comment: @MushyPeas put cursor on the class you want to move/extract

Comment: It always moves a class to another file or class (in both options). To move the class to the current file, just cut and paste it, as usually.